# How to display the CFG of a function in Ghidra?

Tags: disassembly, ghidra

I am currently trying [Ghidra](https://www.ghidra-sre.org/) and, I am looking at a specific function. I have the assembly code and the decompiled version of it. But, I am looking to see if I can have it as a CFG...

Does someone has a clue on how to do it?

[image: Ghidra screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `Window` -> `Function Graph`

Its even conveniently zoomable.

[image: interface]